# jQuery: Get HTML as well as input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have a variable store the HTML in a div tag, but simply using `var a = $('div').html()` doesn't store the values of the input tags that lie within the div.

So, my question is, how should I go about saving the HTML *and* the selected options and values of input tags to a variable using jQuery?

Here is some example code:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <select name="word">
    <option value="1">Placeholder 1</option>
    <option value="2">Placeholder 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
/* "a" should also have the user values, such that when I use $('body').append(a), 
it has the same user input as the div. */

var a = $('div').html();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could [`$.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element.

```
var $a = $("div:first").clone();

$a.appendTo("body"); // Clone invades your body
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/obebov/edit

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about `.clone()`.  Just tested it, works great.

Comment: The selected option in the <select> tag doesn't get cloned.

Comment: @Ivan Are you saying the `<option/>` no longer exists, or is not selected?

Comment: Not selected (Sorry for the confusion).

Comment: @Ivan You'll have to set the `$.val()` of the clone based upon the `$.val()` of the original. `$clone = $orig.clone().val($orig.val()).appendTo("body");`

Answer (score 7):

You may also achieve this by first changing the value of input fields uding DOM like this:

```
$('div input').each(function(){
    $(this).keyup(function(){
        $(this).attr('value',$(this).val());
    });
});
```

after which you can extract the HTML by using this:

```
$('div').html();
```

Comment: For using select as well:

            if($(this).is('select'))
            {
                $(this).find('option:selected').attr('selected', 'selected');                    
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
            }

Answer (score 0):

If the document having `Ajax` content, the best solution would be:

```
$(document).on("keyup change", "input", function () {
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});
```

You must use both `change` and `keyup` event.